# Are there any airports in the world which offer shower facilities for everyone?

Tags: air-travel, airports

This might be a stupid question (or not) but from my very very limited experience there are only toilets and restaurants in most airports. I know Airports are a business and they exist so they can make money from f&b and any shopping you do between changing planes. Are there any airports which offer showering facilities (even if some small charge is there) so that you don't end up looking haggard after a long flight. I was thinking about my hypothetical run between BOM and Montreal, Canada.

Comment: Hi Shirish - yes, it's very common, but you do have to pay.  Another common thing these days is "sleeping stalls" - kind of a mini-hotel where you can sleep for a few hours (again you pay of course).

Comment: If you are new to flying, note that Zach is explaining "Lounges", which is another thing.  Airlines have "Lounges" which are luxurious waiting rooms, which can be used by people flying business class, etc.  Or, you can just pay to use a Lounge.  (A few lounges offer showers.)  This is not relevant to you, you won't have Lounge access.

Comment: I just did a quick google for you and unfortunately there are no showers-for-hire businesses at IST airport.  You would have to pay money to use a Lounge as Zach explains.  I instantly googled info on this, example http://www.istanbultravelbook.com/before-you-go-topic.php?rel=Pay-for-use-Lounges_at_Istanbul_Airport  You'll pay about 4000 Inr to use a lounge.

Comment: same in Frankfurt, for only 7 euro you can take a hot water shower and shine bright like a rainbow to you final destination :)

Comment: Asking about any airport in the world is overly broad and, in any case, not a useful question. Suppose you got the answer "All airports in Australia have showers." (I've no idea if that's actually true; it's just an example.) How would that help you if, say, you were flying from India to the UK? That also makes the question essentially hypothetical.

Comment: I was asking any because I had that feeling that not every airport would be so commercially-minded as to have lounges for getting a shower. And thankfully, that came true. I wish there was a  website/list where you could see which airports have shower facilities. I did see sleepingairports.net but didn't see a way to figure out what I needed.

Comment: How silly.  The question "do airports now offer paid shower facilities?" is a terrific question guys.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many airports offer shower facilities as part of various lounges. Lounges are generally available to first/business class passengers and some frequent flyers, but some lounges are also accessible upon payment of a fee. Not all lounges have showers, but many do, especially those catering to long-haul international passengers.

There are hundreds of airports with lounges throughout the world, and every one has slightly different policies as to who can access what lounges, what services are available inside, and which lounges are physically reachable on a given journey (some lounges may be in a different terminal or only available to passengers before or after immigration or security). The app [LoungeBuddy](https://www.loungebuddy.com/) can help you find lounges, see what they offer, and purchase access if this is an option. You can also ask a specific question here if you give your detailed itinerary and need help finding your options.

In addition, some airports may have separate shower facilities, which aren't full lounges, but offer a shower, typically for a fee. You can look for these on an airport's website. The website [sleepinginairports.net](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/) also has detailed information about many airports. If you scroll down to the page where it lists the airport's services and facilities, it may list any available showers. That site also has information about airport lounges that are accessible upon payment of a fee.

Comment: sleepinginairports.net is in my experience often out-of-date and inaccurate.

Comment: I would always try to confirm something like sleepinginairports.net against the airport's website if I needed to rely on it. Some airports have horrible websites that don't always list this information though, so checking multiple places can help.

Answer (score 8):

Many do; see for example [London Heathrow](http://www.heathrow.com/airport-guide/terminal-facilities-and-services/toilets-and-showers), [Dubai International](http://www.dubaiairports.ae/while-youre-here/services), or [Tokyo Narita](http://www.narita-airport.jp/en/guide/service/list/svc_37.html#t1).

Strangely, I looked at a couple major North American airports, and couldn't find any that does.

Comment: unfortunately on the OPs run from BOM to Montreal, they'll realistically have to fly Turkish.  I don't know if there's a shower-stall business in IST.

Comment: @Joe This wasn't the question, though.

Comment: Sure - I didn't say it was.  I voted up your answer as it's correct.  Someone reading who transits IST a lot may specifically know and drop in a comment here; good use of comments area.

Comment: Because of US transit-visa requirements, and simple geography, US airports are rarely international layovers.  Showers aren't that interesting during a short domestic layover between two short domestic flights.

Comment: @joeBlow are you telling/sharing that turkish airlines has direct or inter-connecting flights from BOM to Montreal (single airline), if yes, that is good to know. Have upvoted you as at least one option gets narrowed down.

Comment: hi @shirish yes Turkish has real flights from BOM to Montreal, SINGLE AIRLINE (no codeshare bullshit), so that's two legs. One from BOM to Istanbul, one from Istanbul to Montreal.  As a broad general rule when you are flying from India to Europe, just take Emirates (change in Dubai).  If traveling from India to somewhere in North America, very unfortunately Emirates only goes to a small set of North American cities, so you have to change somewhere in Europe. It's usually necessary to change airlines / codeshare. Often Lufthansa is an ok, for example. (Munich/Frankfort is great to change in.)

Comment: Please note @shirish that you can get this information instantaneously from EXPEDIA.COM in a fraction of the time it takes to type out one of these sentences.  You don't have to actually fly using expedia, to use their web site to find out which flights are direct.