# What exactly are sleeping stalls versus waiting-rooms, for airport layovers?

Tags: airports, layovers, sleeping

Somebody shared about "sleeping stalls" as a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82018/are-there-any-airports-in-the-world-which-offer-shower-facilities-for-everyone/82020#comment190053_82018) in my previous question. Could somebody elaborate (hopefully with a picture or some link) which tell/share more about sleeping stalls and how they are different from waiting rooms. For instance, the waiting room in Doha, Qatar International Airport was "free" but one couldn't sleep unless one had a bed-sheet or something to put underneath and were ready to sleep on the floor. The only thing you could do is to sleep on a beach-chair/recliner which is not good for obese people like me.

Comment: What are you confused about?  You pay (say, 10 or 15 dollars an hour) and you get to use a "tiny hotel room" to sleep in. They have an actual bed and so on - quite simply it's a "very small hotel" you can use per hour.  (Some also have showers, it varies.)  Many large airports have businesses offering this service now. There are a number of well-known brands such as **Yotel**.  The waiting room in Doha is just a "waiting room". It has nothing to do with a business selling you small cabins per hour.

Comment: Note that on incredibly long flights like Sydney-Paris or Bombay-Montreal. Many people prefer to **actually make a stopover night** on the way.  In your case you'd fly to Istanbul, actually stop for the whole night.  Just stay at the cheapest airport hotel.  (Forget about sightseeing, sightseeing is crap.) Then the NEXT day fly on to Montreal.  If you plan this well it actually won't cost you much more money. Often flying with (say) children it's much better to do this.

Comment: I've found that interestingly you normally have to book direct with the airline (phone them) to have a flight with a stopover; for some reason you can't do it in expedia.  Often it actually does not cost a cent more to have a stopover.

Comment: @JoeBlow: interesting. Can you cite anything on whether this reduces sleep disruption/jetlag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Yotel](http://www.yotel.com/en/hotels/london-heathrow-airport/cabins) for example. There are pictures in the link, but possibly are copyrighted. These differ from waiting rooms as those are usually free. 'Cabins' such as Yotel's are more akin to hotel rooms, but generally much smaller and obviously without hotel facilities such as room service.

More like a luggage locker but for people rather than bags.

There are also [sleeping pods](http://blog.sleepinginairports.net/2014/03/25/airport-sleeping-pods/).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what Joe meant in his comment but I could think of e.g.

- closed cubicles as in the [napcabs](http://www.munich-airport.de/en/consumer/aufenthalt_trans/hotels/napcabs/index.jsp) in Munich airport
- barely divided mattresses (much like a hostel) in [Zurich airports airside hotel](https://www.zurich-airport.com/passengers-and-visitors/airport-services-en/layover-and-lounges/transit-hotel-bedrooms)

Comment: I was referring to the "rest area" (2nd pic). There the price list is per "Couch in rest area" for those stalls, i.e. you'd get one of these stalls with a couch/mattress/whatever you call that black thing in the pics. @pnuts btw great link, +1 again if I had not already

Comment: whoa you can be out of votes??